# Class owning and sharing an object simultaneously

Tags: c++, constructor

I consider writing a class that behaves differently, depending on its construction method:

Example:

```
// #1 - Own an object
class MyClass {
    MyClass(std::string const& str) : m_str(str) {}

    std::string m_str;
}

// #2 - Share an object (Can be done by pointer as well)
class MyClass {
    MyClass(std::string& str) : m_str(str) {}

    std::string& m_str;
}
```

1. Is this a good idea to have both behaviors in the same class?
2. What is the best way to implement such a class?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have a class that sometimes is responsible of the deallocation of its data and some other times it only references it and allows higher level logic to access it and deallocate it in time.

Comment: Ideally a class should be doing one "thing", not two. Have you considered managing deallocation separately from the higher level logic? For example always have a reference in MyClass and create a copy of the string just before constructing MyClass when it's necessary.

Comment: I did. It introduces potential problems. What if `MyClass` outlives `str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct MyClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> dont_touch_me;
    std::string & str;

    explicit MyClass(std::string const & s)
    : dont_touch_me(new std::string(s))
    , str(*dont_touch_me)
    { }

    explicit MyClass(std::string & r)
    : str(r)
    { }
};
```

Now just make sure you always use `MyClass::str` for everything.

Comment: @Albert: That's impossible to answer out of context. If it fits and solves your problem, then I don't see an immediate reason not to use it...

Comment: I think a named constructor would be more appropriate as I could own (copy) a non-const string if I want to. I also think that `dont_touch_me` should be a smart pointer as it might take unnecessary space if `string` is replaced by more complex class.

Comment: What about named constructor? Current implementation doesn't allow copying a non-const string.

Comment: @Albert: Just cast it if you want the copying behaviour. Or if you must, add a tag to the constructor or something like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15341/discussion-between-albert-and-kerrek-sb)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ReferenceHolder
{
private:
    std::string& m_str;
public:
    ReferenceHolder(std::string& str) : m_str(str) {}
    // ... all other methods operating on m_str
};

struct ValueHolder : public ReferenceHolder
{
private:
    std::string m_str;
public:
    ValueHolder(const std::string& str) : ReferenceHolder(m_str), m_str(str) {}
};
```

This is not really a good idea to combine both behaviors in a single class, because objects constructed with non-const reference will make no use of internal string. If caller can decide whether to pass const or non-const reference to constructor, it must be of no difficulty to decide between two class names.

The overhead of holding both `std::string` and reference is rather small though. If you want to seamlessly pass around your object with string inside by value, then you should do it as Kerrek SB suggested.